# Runnig process with proc_open

Tags: php, c, stdin

I have one php script and I want to call a process writting in C from the PHP scrit. There are many ways to do it(system,exec...), but Ï chosse the function **proc_open**. With this I can open a pipe in stdin and stdout with the C process, but I don´t know how to get the data from stdin in the C process. Can anyone help me with a example?.Thank you

Comment: This isn't a PHP question. Could be titled "How can I access stdin in C".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are constant `FILE` pointers defined in `<stdio.h>`. For example, to read from stdin:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int ch = fgetc(stdin); //read 1 character from stdin
    fputc(ch, stdout);  //dump to stdout
    //...
    return 0;
}
```